# Continous Build Integration with SourceSafe and Batch Files

Tags: .net, continuous-integration, build-automation, visual-sourcesafe, batch-file

I want to create a continuous build integration system for .NET using just Windows batch files and Visual Source Safe.

I've come up with the following batch file so far -

```
set ssdir=\\xxxx\vss
cd d:\mydir
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual SourceSafe\ss.exe" diff "$/sourcedir" -R -Q > diffout.txt
```

This will spit out a file containg lines like "SourceSafe files different from local files" when a change has been made.

My challenge is to figure out if those lines are in the file, then do a get and kick off MSBuild if they are. I'd then schedule the batch file to run every 10 minutes or so.

Anyone got any thoughts on how to do that? Or any other ways of doing continuous build integration without downloading a complicated build automation system?

**Update:** Happy to use cscript or powershell too, though not really familiar with those environments. My main aim is to avoid installing 3rd party software

Comment: did you get final solution  using ***batch file*** option ? full script sample about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cmd.exe is a dinosaur. Here's a PowerShell version.

```
Set-Alias ss 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual SourceSafe\ss.exe'
Set-Alias msbuild 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework64\v3.5\msbuild.exe'

cd d:\mydir

$diffs = ss diff '$/sourcedir' -R -Q

if ($diffs -match 'SourceSafe files different') {
    msbuild blah
}
```

Comment: One thing I should point out if you're unfamiliar with PowerShell. Be careful when putting $ in strings. I used the single-quote string syntax which doesn't expand variables. If you use double quotes, PowerShell will try to expand variables, for example: $s = 'hello'; write-host "$s world!";

Comment: I've got this working now - it's sweet. I can even send an email from it. Very nice!

Comment: Check out PowerShell Community Extensions (http://www.codeplex.com/pscx) for a ton of additional PowerShell functionality.

Answer (score 4):

[hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) is not a very complicated thing to get running.  Even i managed to get it working in a short amount of time.

And while you're at it, replace sourcesafe...

Comment: Agreed SS should go. I like Team Foundation Server and I'm just one guy. The "reject checkin if build fails" is nice.

Answer (score 2):

**Writing your own is a good way to learn but** I'd suggest that things like maven and cruise control are very simple to get running.

However if dead keen on writing your own, I'd write a [filewatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) that watches the files in the [VSS Shadow Folders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byx8tbka(VS.80).aspx) and then kicks off MSBUILD.

Comment: Good point about trying to write your own as a great learning tool...  I did that at one place and am now happily using hudson.